# Is it okay to pack a disposable razor in checked baggage entering Haneda Airport?

Tags: luggage, japan, prohibited-items

I am leaving for Japan next week and my port of entry there is Haneda Airport. I'm wondering if they allow a disposable razor in a checked baggage.

Comment: Razors are much more of an issue at the departure airport than at the arrival airport, and only for cabin baggage.

Answer (score 2):

Yes indeed. I fly several times a year to Japan, generally landing in Haneda, and have had disposable razors every time in my luggage.

Customs officers - who inspect everybody and every piece of luggage, don't care about razors.

Comment: Yet another ridiculous downvote...

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is fine. According to [this infographic](http://www.haneda-airport.jp/inter/dept/dangerous_goods.pdf) from their website, you can even bring straight razors and knives in checked luggage, so a disposable razor will be okay.

Comment: That concerns people leaving from Haneda, not arriving there.